# Comparing several Datatables with same structure

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm creating Datatables from .csv files. This part actually works. My current issue is the following one:
I have to compare two or more Datatable's with the same structure. So

Datatable1:
**KeyColumn, ValueColumn**
KeyA, ValueA
KeyB, ValueB
KeyC, ValueC

Datatable2: 
**KeyColumn, ValueColumn**
KeyB, ValueB
KeyC, ValueC
KeyD, ValueD

And this should end up like this:

ResultDatatable:
**KeyColumn, ValueColumn (of DT1), ValueColumn (of DT2)**
KeyA, ValueA
KeyB, ValueB (of DT1), ValueB (of DT2)
KeyC, ValueC (of DT1), ValueC (of DT2)
KeyD,                       ValueD

I can't even manage to insert the Data of the first Datatable because of different ColumnNames. Another problem is, that the Datatables own the same ColumnNames, so I can't add those to the ResultDatatable.

I have tried many ways and end up with no solution. Any ideas how to address this problem?

Edit:
The solution with Dictionaries was too sophisticated, so I continued trying to solve it with the Datatables. The source of the problem was something very unexpected. 
The attempt to rename a column name to something, **which contains a simple dot** ('.') results with **losing all data** in that column. 
e.g. If you have Datatable dt: 
**PrimaryColumn, ValueColumn** 
KeyA1,     KeyB1
KeyA2,     KeyB2 

After 
dt.Columns[ValueColumn].ColumnName = "Value.Column";
 You **will lose** any data in that column. I will ask MS, if this is desired or if it is a Bug in the .NET-Framework. 
 Here is my final Code (C#). I have List<string>keys which will remain in the resultTable. and List<string>values which will be added for every Table that should be compared.

```
private DataTable CompareTables(List<AnalyseFile> files, Query query, List<string> keys, List<string> values) {
            // Add first table completely to resultTable
            DataTable resultTable =
                files[0].GetDataTable(false, query.Header, query.Startstring, query.Endstring, query.Key).Copy();
            foreach (string value in values) {
                resultTable.Columns[value].ColumnName = "(" + files[0].getFileNameWithoutExtension() + ") " + value;
            }

            // Set primary keys
            resultTable.PrimaryKey = keys.Select(key => resultTable.Columns[key]).ToArray();

            // process remaining tables
            for (int i = 1; i < files.Count; i++) {
                DataTable currentTable = files[i].GetDataTable(false, query.Header, query.Startstring, query.Endstring, query.Key);
                // Add value-columns to the resultTable
                foreach (string value in values) {
                    resultTable.Columns.Add("(" + files[i].getFileNameWithoutExtension() + ") " + value);
                }

                // Set again primary keys
                currentTable.PrimaryKey = keys.Select(key => currentTable.Columns[key]).ToArray();

                // populate common Rows 
                foreach (DataRow dataRow in resultTable.Rows) {
                    foreach (DataRow row in currentTable.Rows) {
                        foreach (string key in keys) {
                            if (dataRow[key].ToString().Equals(row[key].ToString())) {
                                foreach (string value in values) {
                                    string colname = "(" + files[i].getFileNameWithoutExtension() + ") " + value;
                                    dataRow[colname] = row[value];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Get all Rows, which do not exist in resultTable yet
                IEnumerable<string> isNotinDT =
                    currentTable.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(row => row.Field<string>(keys[0]))
                        .Except(resultTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>(keys[0])));

                // Add all the non existing rows to resulTable
                foreach (string row in isNotinDT) {
                    DataRow currentRow = currentTable.Rows.Find(row);
                    DataRow dRow = resultTable.NewRow();
                    foreach (string key in keys) {
                        dRow[key] = currentRow[key];
                    }
                    foreach (string value in values) {
                        dRow["(" + files[i].getFileNameWithoutExtension() + ") " + value] = currentRow[value];
                    }
                    resultTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
                }
            }    

            return resultTable;
        }
```

Any improvements are Welcome!

Comment: Two Questions. 1) Do you have to use Datatables because it seems like Dictionaries would be a better Choice. 2) what Are The DataTypes of KeyColumn and ValueColumn?

Comment: Are these tables already stored in a database? And, if yes, what kind of database?

Comment: @BrandonJohnson Yes using Dictionaries seems like to be the better choice, I could read the csv files into them and then create my ResultTable using those. Thank you

Comment: @Steve No, I do not use a database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Here is an example of my version using the dictionaries.

**Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/AljK9J**

```
    //Setup Sample Data
    var data1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data1.Add("KeyA", "ValueA");
    data1.Add("KeyB", "ValueB");
    data1.Add("KeyC", "ValueC");

    var data2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data2.Add("KeyB", "ValueB");
    data2.Add("KeyC", "ValueC");
    data2.Add("KeyD", "ValueD");


    //Second DataType in the Dictionary could be something other than a Tuple
    var result = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();

    //Fill in for items existing only in data1 and in both data1 and data2
    foreach(var item in data1)
    {
        result.Add(item.Key, new Tuple<string, string>(item.Value, data2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.Key).Value));
    }

    //Fill in remaining items that exist only in data2
    foreach(var item in data2.Where(d2 => !result.Any(x => x.Key == d2.Key )))
    {
        result.Add(item.Key, new Tuple<string, string>(null, item.Value));
    }

    //Demonstrating how to access the data
    var formattedOutput = result.Select(x => string.Format("{0}, {1} (of D1), {2} (of D2)", x.Key, x.Value.Item1 ?? "NoValue", x.Value.Item2 ?? "NoValue"));

    foreach(var line in formattedOutput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

Comment: Using Dictionaries made me hit on an Idea. I could read the csv files into Dictionaries and use them to create my ResultTable.